# Calling TextToSpeech from a different class

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am trying to call TextToSpeech in a different class.
Here are what my classes look like right now:

```
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  private SpeechRecognizer sr;
  sr.setRecognitionListener(new Listener());
}


//Listener.java
public class Listener implements RecognitionListener() {
  public void onResults(Bundle 
    MainActivity theMainActivity = new MainActivity();

    //the following line always breaks the code:
    tts = new TextToSpeech(theMainActivity, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {/*...*/});
  }
}
```

For context, the file in its context is [on GitHub](https://github.com/hexicle/soctalk/blob/008901d9bfcd20e1f07104ad9da0efd785fb689c/soctalk/app/src/main/java/com/kuhanmuniam/soctalk/MainActivity.java). The version on GitHub is the working version where everything is in `MainActivity.java`, but I am attempting to move `Listener` out into its own class `Listener.java`.

The error received is `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference`.

Now for my long explanation of what I have tried...

### What I've tried

When I tried replacing `theMainActivity` with `MainActivity.this` and get the error `MainActivity is not an enclosing class`.  I understood that I could either make Listener a static class (but won't compile), or I could instantiate new MainActivity().new Listener() (but won't compile).
Someone asked the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) which itself is marked a duplicate. So my question is a duplicate of a duplicate... However there was no explicit answer given.

I understand that I'm supposed to somehow [solve the NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). However, when I log the value right before usage it is not null at all. Instead  `theMainActivity` has value `com.package.name.MainActivity@b76325e` in `Log.d`. So if it's not null in the first place, yet throws a null error, how could it be fixed?

So I figured maybe it's Android-specific. After all, it has something to do with android ContentResolver...
So I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199308/android-content-context-getcontentresolver-on-a-null-object-reference) and thought that creating an application [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) would work, except that my MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity instead of Application so I cannot write MainActivity.context.

I understand that I am missing out on some fundamental Java understanding. I get that there is an Application and Activity context for applications. I get that the problem has to do with getting context in Listener.java. I also get that somehow I need to bring the context into Listener.java. And I know that simply running `new MainActivity()` in Listener.java is probably a bad idea because I should be using the original MainActivity Activity context which called onResults in the first place. The best solution I can think of is somehow making the context a 'global' in some way that can be accessed by any class, or something like that... but I keep running into pitfalls like "it's not static" and "no you can't call use android.content.Context because you're not using android.app.Application".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
//Listener.java
public class Listener implements RecognitionListener() {
 MainActivity instance;
 public Listener(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.instance = mainActivity;
 }
  public void onResults(Bundle 
    MainActivity theMainActivity = new MainActivity();

    //the following line always breaks the code:
    tts = new TextToSpeech(instance, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {/*...*/});
  }
}
//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  private SpeechRecognizer sr;
  sr.setRecognitionListener(new Listener(this));
}
```

Comment: It worked! So this is how to handle the Activity context.

Comment: Glad it helped :)